# Cloudflare ssl certificate without being under proxy server

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, dns, cloudflare

i activated ssl on my website through cloudflare,i have a page which keeps ip addresses of visitors, but all ip addresses that are logged are ips of proxy servers of cloudflare.
when i try to turn off proxy by changing orange cloud to grey one ssl certificate is no longer avaliable.
Im trying to keep ssl certificate and get rid of proxy.
Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Cloudflare has the certificate and the private key to it. The TLS connection is terminated at the infrastructure from Cloudflare, i.e. Cloudflare will always be a reverse proxy for this final target.

If you don't want to have a proxy in front get your own certificate (for example using Let's Encrypt), but then you also don't get any protection from Cloudflare. If you want to use Cloudflare as reverse proxy but want to know the original IP of the client see [Restoring original visitor IPs: logging visitor IP addresses](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170786-Restoring-original-visitor-IPs-logging-visitor-IP-addresses).